# Создание рубрик программно

Tags: php, wordpress

Допустим в цикле создаются записи, и нужно сразу в этом же цикле назначать новым записям рукрики.

```
foreach ($arrayRubrics as $rubrica => $cont) {
    echo 'rubrica - '.$rubrica .'<br>';
    foreach ($cont as $title=> $values) {
        $content = $values['content'];
        $args = array(
            'post_title'   => $title,
            'post_content' => $content,
            'post_type'    => 'test',
            'post_status'  => 'publish'
        );
        $post_id = wp_insert_post(wp_slash($args));

        wp_set_post_terms($post_id, $rubrica, 'tax_test', true);
    }
}
```

arrayRubrics - это многомерный массив, в котором ключ это название рубрики, а вложенный массив - это контент, который нужно создавать в цикле и назначать каждой записи текущую рубрику.
Почему этот код не создаёт для записей рубрики? Т.е. в массиве могут быть рубрики, которые ещё не созданы. Нужно в этом цикле создавать рубрики и сразу же назначать эти рубрики новым записям. В документации сказано, что по идее функция wp_set_post_terms должна создавать рубрики, которых ещё нет. Но в данном коде новые рубрики не создаются.
Подскажите, как нужно создавать и сразу же назначать эти новые рубрики новым записям?
В коде используется таксономия tax_test, которая создаётся при активации плагина и назначается данному типу записи

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: А как создана таксономия tax_test? Она иерархическая или нет?

Comment: я уже решил эту задачу с помощью wp_set_object_terms

Comment: Опубликуйте ваше решение как ответ, возможно кому-нибудь тоже пригодится

Comment: wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $rubrica, 'tax_test' );